# Scala / Specs2 : def is(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) = { "Service" should {...} }

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2

I try to upgrade a Scala/Play project to Play 2.7, Scala 2.12.11, Specs2 4.5.1.

In the project there is the following Specs2 test that I cannot understand in the sense of its Specs2 specification structure (could be that the Specs2 API changed a lot since the test was written).

When I looked at the [structure of specifications](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-2.4.17/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html) in the current API, I could not see any example of `is` method combined together with `should`.

**What was it supposed to mean?**

**How can I rewrite such a specification in the current Specs2 API?**

I also noticed that the test code used `import org.specs2.mutable.Specification` instead of `import org.specs2.Specification` which is supposed to be used when using the `is` method.
And it uses `def is(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv)`, instead of `def is`.

Here is the old test:

```
package services

import org.specs2.concurrent.ExecutionEnv
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.mutable.ExecutionEnvironment
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.api.test.WithApplication
import play.modules.reactivemongo._

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class StatisticsServiceSpec() extends Specification with ExecutionEnvironment {

  def is(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) = {
    "The StatisticsService" should {

      "compute and publish statistics" in new WithApplication() {
        val repository = new MongoStatisticsRepository(configuredAppBuilder.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi])
        val wsTwitterService = new WSTwitterService
        val service = new DefaultStatisticsService(repository, wsTwitterService)

        val f = service.createUserStatistics("elmanu")

        f must beEqualTo(()).await(retries = 0, timeout = 5.seconds)
      }

    }

    def configuredAppBuilder = {
      import scala.collection.JavaConversions.iterableAsScalaIterable

      val env = play.api.Environment.simple(mode = play.api.Mode.Test)
      val config = play.api.Configuration.load(env)
      val modules = config.getStringList("play.modules.enabled").fold(
        List.empty[String])(l => iterableAsScalaIterable(l).toList)

      new GuiceApplicationBuilder().
        configure("play.modules.enabled" -> (modules :+
          "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule")).build
    }
  }

}
```

To simplify the code down to the actual Specs2 API, I think it could be reduced to something like this:

```
package services

import org.specs2.concurrent.ExecutionEnv
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.test.WithApplication

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class StatisticsServiceSpec(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification /* with ExecutionEnvironment */ {

  def is(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) = {

    "The StatisticsService" should {

      "compute and publish statistics" in new WithApplication() {

        val f = Future(1)

        f must beEqualTo(1).await(retries = 0, timeout = 5.seconds)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pay attention that I removed the `ExecutionEnvironment` trait, since it seems to have been removed from the library.

Now, the code finally compiles, but when I try to run the test, there are no errors, but no test is actually run: the output is `Empty test suite.`

Answer (score 3):

The new specification should be

```
package services

import org.specs2.concurrent.ExecutionEnv
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.test.WithApplication

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class StatisticsServiceSpec(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification {
  "The StatisticsService" should {
    "compute and publish statistics" in new WithApplication() {
      val f = Future(1)
      f must beEqualTo(1).await(retries = 0, timeout = 5.seconds)
    }
  }
}
```

The `ExecutionEnv` is now really supposed to be retrieved as a specification member directly (with an `implicit` to be make it available to the `await` method).

`is` is not necessary in a "mutable" specification. `is` is the function in a `Specification` where you declare all the "Fragments" of your specification (a `Fragment` is a `Description` + an `Execution`). In a mutable specification this function is automatically populated from the fact that you trigger method calls *directly in the body of the class* when the specification is instantiated. The fragments created by `should` and `in` are collected in a mutable variable, hence the name "mutable specification".

If you define `def is(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv)`, this is like defining another, valid, `is` definition that specs2 doesn't know about, while not creating anything for the `def is: Fragments` method. That's why you end up with an empty specification.

Comment: PS: good luck with the rest of the migration, don't hesitate to ask again :-)

Comment: Thank you...! The simplified code now works (it compiles, and the test succeeds)... and it makes sense. I was trying to adjust the first excerpt, hence the delay... I noticed that sometimes the IDE (Intellij) unjustifiably complains that it cannot find an implicit `ExecutionEnv` class for the `in` method. Your thoughts?... What it the idea behind calling the method `is`? What is the meaning of `WithApplication`? Are the different contexts discussed on the online guide I linked to earlier? Could not find `WithApplication` there...